# Google Drive Thumbnails getting 403 Rate-Limit Exceeded

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

We have an application with a library feature that shares photos/documents between users. The basic flow and problem is as follows:

1. A user shares a file in the application which makes a file public unlisted.
2. Other users can request the list of files currently shared with the group.
3. They then request the meta data the about any files they want to list, which includes a thumbnail url which we then display.

Usually the thumbnails come up just fine but sometimes we begin getting 403's. After a while they will begin working again without us changing anything. A few other items worth mentioning are:

1. The actual API calls never seem to hit any limits. We get this issue even when we are just requesting a single file. The console in Google doesn't show any exceeded limits as far as we can tell.
2. If you open up the thumbnail in a separate tab it always seems to come up without any problem.
3. When it goes into this mode all of our developers seem to hit it at the same time,  hence we are guessing it is linked to some limit from our application but we can't seem to find any limits we are exceeding. (Note: Our developers work from home so they all have different IP addresses.)
4. The details of our 403's can be found below.

We are guessing it isn't related to the following:

1. Making too many requests concurrently since we get the problem even when we do a single file.
2. Not being authorized since (a) the files are public unlisted, (b) we just logged in, and (c) when you open the thumbnail in a tab it shows up just fine.

Any ideas?

[image: Images with 403s]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Screenshot of our Google Drive quotas
[image]

Comment: there are two limits. daily limits and rate limits. rate limits are within a given second. for how long do you see the 403? also look at the api console and see if it shows the limit reached there.

Comment: I can find the Drive API quota's in the Google console. Is that what you mean by rate limit? Where can I find if I am hitting the second limit you speak of?  (I updated the post to show a screenshot of our quota screen)

Comment: @aashtonk - Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @TMan Sadly we never did figure out what the problem was. This was partially due to the fact that we couldn't consistently recreate it. It would just randomly begin happening, and then it would just stop after a while.

Comment: @aashtonk Did the problem appear in production as well?

Comment: @raz3r Sadly its been so long since I was on this project I no longer remember.

Answer (score 20):

My "solution" was to use the new `referrerpolicy` and set it to `no-referrer` in the image element.

```
<img referrerPolicy="no-referrer" src="GOOGLE_THUMBNAIL_IMAGE_LINK"/>
```

The attribute is experimental according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-referrerpolicy). At time of writing, it's supported on Chrome and Firefox only, so not a real fix. The theory behind it working is the `no-referrer` means the image request is the same as the one used when you go directly to the link (where the thumbnail seems to always work).

Comment: Have you tried this in a production environment? Did it work?

Comment: @raz3r Problem is users with old browsers, but for the internal company site we built it does fine.

Comment: Worked for me. For Google profile pictures hosted through Firebase auth.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Weird

Answer (score 5):

After a few days of experimentation, I'm pretty sure this is caused by accessing the URLs in question from a `localhost` environment. Whenever I push to production, the quota limit resolves itself for thumbnails I'm attempting to access from Google.

While I don't have conclusive proof that this is the case, it definitely makes sense given the observed behavior.

Comment: Hmm I think we mostly saw it in our Dev and QA environments.  I wonder if it could be related to non-public urls. I don't know I ever saw it in Prod.

Comment: Same thing is happening to me. It comes and goes without any consistent behavior. As mentioned, it only seems to happen when accessing the page from `localhost`. After going live the issue did not seem to appear. I'm guessing Google has a limit on the number of requests that can come from localhost. If too many people are making these calls from `localhost` then the rate limit is surpassed.