# Google drive API thumbnail not displayed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-drive-api

I can not get all thumbnails using Google Drive API. They are randomly displayed.
Here is the code I use:

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function gapiLoaded() {
        gapi.load('client', intializeGapiClient);
      }

      async function intializeGapiClient() {
         await gapi.client.setToken({access_token:'ya29.a0AVvZVs...'});
         loadDriveApi();
        };

      function loadDriveApi() {
        gapi.client.load('drive', 'v3', listFiles);
      }

      function listFiles() {
        var parentID = 'root'; 
        var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
          'q': `'${parentID}' in parents and trashed = false`,
          'fields': "nextPageToken, files(id,thumbnailLink,size,webViewLink,parents,shared,name,createdTime,mimeType,properties)",
        });
        _files = [];
        i = 0;
        request.execute(function(resp) {
        var files = resp.files;
        if (files && files.length > 0) {
          for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            var file = files[i];
            _files += file.id+'|'+file.name+'|'+file.size+'|'+file.thumbnailLink+'|'+file.mimeType+'|'+file.webViewLink+'|'+file.parents+'|'+file.createdTime+'\r\n';
            if (i+1 == files.length){
              console.log(_files);
            }
          }
        }
        });
      }
 
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoaded();"></script>
```

and here is animated gif displaying the result: https://i.postimg.cc/26FMy6Hs/g1.gif
How to get all thumbnails, please?

Comment: 403 is likely to be some kind of rate limit. Are you hosting this on a `localhost`? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41751941) says that it seems that there's a stricter rate limit on localhost sites.

Comment: Looks like it works on real domain. Thank you so much. Why Google didn't say that anywhere?